# Getting data from HTML to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-4

I am using this HTML code (bootstrap) to allow users to enter tags

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput"> <span class="tag label label-info">test tag<span data-role="remove"></span></span> <span class="tag label label-info">testing <span data-role="remove"></span></span> <span class="tag label label-info">issue <span data-role="remove"></span></span> <input size="1" type="text"> </div>
```

So the output

[image]

My question is, I cannot figure out how do I read this text in C# (asp.net Web forms) because it's not ASP:TextBox

Is this possible to read these tags in C#?

Thank you

Comment: C# can not directly read these html tag. But you can use client side scripting to read those tag and pass it to C# method.

Comment: I think you need to specify "Web Forms"

Comment: Yes, i meant web forms - Thanks Keith

Comment: my guess, and I'm not good at webforms ( bit of a hater ), you need a hidden input, then some javascript to hook changes to your tags, and update the hidden input with the tag data, then on posback you should get your tags

Comment: @KeithNicholas WOW, I thought there might be a better way for this -

Comment: see the answer, looks like a better way :)

Comment: @aliusman check on my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So by looking at the documentation here: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ you should be applying `data-role="tagsinput"` to the input element. This means you should be able to do something like:

**Important Update** : I threw this together before my morning coffee had kicked in. Note that `asp:button` has become `asp:TextBox`

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput"> 
   <span class="tag label label-info">test tag<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
   <span class="tag label label-info">testing <span data-role="remove"></span></span> 
   <span class="tag label label-info">issue <span data-role="remove"></span></span> 
   <asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="tags" runat="server" data-role="tagsinput" />       
</div>
```

You can then access the values from `tags` as a comma delimited string.

**Alteratively** you could try

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput"> 
   <span class="tag label label-info">test tag<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
   <span class="tag label label-info">testing <span data-role="remove"></span></span> 
   <span class="tag label label-info">issue <span data-role="remove"></span></span> 
   <input id="tags" runat="server" size="1" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" />       
</div>
```

This will make the text input available as a comma delimited string server side, again using `tags`.

**Finally** the least webformy option, just give the input a `name` attribute

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput"> 
   <span class="tag label label-info">test tag<span data-role="remove"></span></span>
   <span class="tag label label-info">testing <span data-role="remove"></span></span> 
   <span class="tag label label-info">issue <span data-role="remove"></span></span> 
   <input name="tags" size="1" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" />       
</div>
```

You can then access it serverside with `Request.Form["tags"]`, with, you guessed it, the tags as a comma delimited string.

Comment: Tested them all - Solution Number 1 and 3 works great ( i am going with number 3)  - thank you very much, much appreciated

Comment: Jon, what's the meaning of data-role?

Comment: @DiegoS it looks like it is a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) that bootstrap leverages for its tags widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, using JQuery:

Client side:

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput"> 
 <span class="tag label label-info">test tag<span data-role="remove"></span></span> <span class="tag label label-info">testing <span data-role="remove"></span></span> <span class="tag label label-info">issue <span data-role="remove"></span></span> 
 <input size="1" type="text"> 
</div>
<input type="submit" id="sendTagsToServer" text="Send Tags To Server!"/>

<!--Both buttons are invisible, to postback and send parameters-->
<asp:Button ClientIDMode="Static" ID="postbackButton" runat="server" 
Style="display:none;" />
<asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="Static" ID="tagsString" runat="server" />

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sendTagsToServer").on("click",function(){
       //get values from tags
       var tags= $(".tag"); 

       //save values in hidden 
       var tagText = "";           
       tags.each(function(index){
         tagtext = tagText + "&" + $(this).text();         
       });
       $("#tagsString").val(tagText);     

      //postback to server
      $("#postbackButton").click();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Server side:

```
protected void btnPB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //read tags, server side
    string[] param = tagsString.Value.Split("&");
}
```

The trick here is use two inputs, both hidden, one to postback and one to send parametters and of course, you can use Javascript instead of JQuery.

Comment: Why use an asp:Button that is hidden? Why not make `sendTagsToServer` an asp button and use that?

Comment: @JonP i am trying both of your codes, and i think the issue with using simple ASP:Button is, when you press ENTER to add the tag in textbox, it triggers the aps:button on the page - I will get back to you guys

Comment: To avoid using a hidden button you can use the `OnClientClick` attribute to run javascript before the page postback.